# dpdkstats plugin in collectd

Tags: dpdk, collectd

I am trying to record dpdk info using dpdkstats plugin in collectd daemon.
dpdkstats plugin configuration is given below:

```
<Plugin dpdkstat>
        <EAL>
                Coremask "0x2"
                MemoryChannels "4"
                FilePrefix "rte"
                LogLevel "7"
#               RteDriverLibPath "/usr/lib/dpdk-pmd"
        </EAL>
        SharedMemObj "dpdk_collectd_stats_0"
        EnabledPortMask 0xffff
        PortName "interface1"
        PortName "interface2"
</Plugin>
```

and i am getting an error while starting collectd.

```
collectd[46862]: Initialization complete, entering read-loop.
EAL: Detected 24 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Primary and secondary process DPDK version mismatch
EAL: FATAL: Cannot init config
EAL: Cannot init config
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

@SaiGanesh, the cause of error is present in the logs as

```
EAL: Primary and secondary process DPDK version mismatch
EAL: FATAL: Cannot init config
```

So please run your `primary application` and `secondary application -stats daemon` with right DPDK version

Note: humble request to always open with details like

1. DPDK version
2. physical NIC details - firmware and driver
3. interface or HW offloads if any
4. multi-process if any
5. code snippet to reproduce the error